# Get output parameter of a stored procedure camel-sql

Tags: java, sql-server, stored-procedures, apache-camel

I'm writing some routes using camel and running them in JBoss Fuse 6.2.

I want to execute a stored procedure in a SQL Server database and read the value of a output parameter.

I'm making this:

```
from("direct:WRITE_IN_STORED_PROCEDURE")
    .to("sql:exec PROCEDIMIENTO_TEST 'TEST_DATA'?dataSource=dataSource")
    .log(LoggingLevel.INFO, "[${body}]");
```

This route actually WRITE in the database, I checked and the value 'TEST_DATA' is in the database according to the stored procedure logic.

The problem is: I have no idea how to pass and how to read an OUT parameter. The "exec" call is not putting the result of the procedure in the body (like when I use "select").

What must i do?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The sql component do not yet support stored procedures.

There is a ticket: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CAMEL-4725

And there is code in the works: https://github.com/apache/camel/pull/749

You can for example instead use the mybatis component as mybatis supports calling stored procedures: http://camel.apache.org/mybatis

Answer (score -1):

the syntax should be exactly similar to the call as would make from db : mysql below

```
mysql>delimiter // 
mysql>create procedure selectusers(out param1 int) begin select count(*)
   from mysql.user; end//
mysql> delimiter ;
mysql> call selectusers(@param1);
+----------+
| count(*) |
+----------+
|        2 |
+----------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)
```

Similarly from camel your route would now look like below

```
<to uri="sql:exec call selectusers(@param1)?datasource=datasource/>
The result if you print would be as below
[) thread #0 - file://src/data/] rhalling-unmarshalling-exmaple INFO  [{count(*)=2}]
```